# multi-state objects not working on Calibre

Tags: calibre, buttons

I'm looking for a functional reader for the ePub files that I create via InDesign and found Calibre so I'm still learning its features. 
So far I can't find or understand why the multi-state elements (buttons) that I include don't work on it. 
Those work fine on iBooks and some other ebook readers, but on Calibre reader the simply don't respond. 
Is it something I'm missing on the settings? Or is a feature it doesn't automatically comes with the reader and I missed it?

*bonus question, can I block the resizing of the images?